# Transposing and multiply matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have what is effectively a matrix saved as a CSV file. Let's call this matrix 'X'.

What I need to do is take the csv file, read it as a matrix, find it's transpose and then multiply the two together. At the moment I have the following code:

```
import numpy
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("votes.csv","rb"), delimiter=",")
text = list(reader)
result = numpy.matrix(text).astype(int)
print result
```

Which is just supposed to show me the csv file as a matrix of integers but even that is throwing the following error:

```
result = numpy.matrix(text).astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Could anyone help me with this?

If it's of any value the csv is simply filled with positive and negative integer values, separated by commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV contains an empty cell which cannot be parsed into an `int`.

Instead of using `csv.reader`, you can [let numpy to read the CSV directly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), which will also handle these empty or invalid cells for you without raising errors:

```
X = numpy.genfromtxt('1.csv', dtype=int, delimiter=',', filling_values=0)

# compute the matrix multiplication.
result = X.dot(X.T)
```

(here I used `filling_values=0` to replace all empty cells with `0`.)

Use [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save the array into a CSV:

```
numpy.savetxt('2.csv', result, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

(if you don't provide the `fmt` the numbers will be written using scientific notation.)

Comment: That's excellent thanks. I ran numpy.shape(result) and it gave (150L,150L) which is exactly what I was expecting.

Is there a way to turn the matrix back into a csv?

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much, you're a star. I'll mark this as answered now.